# Order a list by substring

Tags: c#

Trying to order a list of strings

```
    List<string> strings = new List<string>() { "N3 2021","N4 2021","N1 2022","N2 2022","N4 2022","N3 2022","N2 2023","N1 2023","N3 2023"};

    var orderedList = strings.OrderBy(x => x.Substring(2).Trim()).ToList();

    Console.WriteLine(String.Join(", ", orderedList));
```

Current Output:

> N3 2021, N4 2021, N1 2022, N2 2022, N4 2022, N3 2022, N2 2023, N1
> 2023, N3 2023

Desired Output:

> N3 2021, N4 2021, N1 2022, N2 2022, N3 2022, N4 2022, N1
> 2023, N2 2023, N3 2023

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

**Update:**

Solution is:

```
List<string> strings = new List<string>() { "N3 2021","N4 2021","N1 2022","N2 2022","N4 2022","N3 2022","N2 2023","N1 2023","N3 2023"};
    
var orderedList = strings.OrderBy(x => x.Substring(2).Trim()).ThenBy(y=>y).ToList();
    
Console.WriteLine(String.Join(", ",orderedList));
```

Comment: It seems like you need `.OrderBy` and then `.ThenBy` since it seems that you want to sort by year and then N number. Is that right?

Comment: How about you provide a FULL and CLEAR explanation of the problem? An example is all well and good but code needs to implement rules so we need to know what the rules are. We shouldn't have to guess them from a single example. Maybe we will get it right but maybe we won't. You already know so there's no reason for us to have to guess.

Comment: @MMK can you add an edit or update on how you get it working ?

Comment: @jmvcollaborator  var orderedList = strings.OrderBy(x => x.Substring(2).Trim()).ThenBy(y=>y.Substring(0)).ToList();

Comment: @MMK `Substring(0)` seems to be a little bit redundand.

Comment: @MMK feel free to post your own solution

Comment: Please don't edit the answer into the question. Post it as an answer.

Answer (score 5):

Seems to me you are sorting by year and then by some sort of prefix code. Since the year is more significant you need to move it to the left of the code for sorting purposes.

```
static string RearrangeString(string input)
{
    var tokens = input.Split(' ');
    return string.Join(" ", tokens.Reverse() );
}

public static void Main()
{
    var strings = new List<string>() { "N3 2021","N4 2021","N1 2022","N2 2022","N4 2022","N3 2022","N2 2023","N1 2023","N3 2023"};
    var orderedList = strings.OrderBy(RearrangeString).ToList();

    Console.WriteLine(String.Join(", ", orderedList));
}
```

[Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Hyn9hM)

Comment: another good approach yet i found @MMK solution much simpler :) UPVOTE tho

Answer (score 0):

Actually solution provided by the author, see question edit.

Here is a [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1Rm7Ys)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        List<string> strings = new List<string>() { "N3 2021","N4 2021","N1 2022","N2 2022","N4 2022","N3 2022","N2 2023","N1 2023","N3 2023"};
    
        var orderedList = strings.OrderBy(x => x.Substring(2).Trim()).ThenBy(y=>y.Substring(0)).ToList();
    
        Console.WriteLine(String.Join(", ",orderedList));
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils no need to argue, it references the author and to not leave the question opened just that.

Comment: *"@MMK can you add an edit or update on how you get it working ?"* Then, your answer.... :/ which is just their solution to their own problem.